# Error when trying to add values to a class array variable in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to create new object and push them to an array. This works when i use a local array `localArr` declared within the method, but seeing `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'blobList' of undefined` when using a class variable `blobList: Azureblob[] = [];`.

[image]

```
 import { Azureblob } from '../models/azureblob';

 export class BlobService {

   blobList: Azureblob[] = [];

   getAllBlobsJS(): Azureblob[] {
      //var localArr = new Array;

      this.blobServiceObj = AzureStorageBlobServiceJS.createBlobService(this.connectionString);

      this.blobServiceObj.listBlobsSegmented('acsazurecontainer', null, function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
          //console.log("**** Error");
        } else {
          for (var i = 0, blob; blob = results.entries[i]; i++) {
            //console.log("**** Success", blob);
            //localArr.push(blob.name);
            this.blobList.push(new Azureblob(blob.name));
        }
     }
     //console.log("**** localArr - Number of blobs returned=", localArr.length);
     console.log("**** Class Arr - blobList length=", this.blobList.length);
     return this.blobList;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference your array from a local variable then use it:

```
var localArr = this.blobList;
[...]
localArr.push(blob.name);
```

Because `this` in your anonymous function doesn't refer to your class instance. It refers to the object that the function is being called.